# Entity Framework using Load with Select - is it possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to optimize my EF queries and I'm stuck with this one.

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
public class House
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Window> Windows { get; set; }
}

public class Window
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public WindowKind Kind { get; set; }
}

public class WindowKind
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to explicitly load all windows and to specify what should be populated in `WindowKind` property.

I know I can do it with `.Include()` like this:

```
var house = Context.Houses.Single(h => h.ID == id);
var windows = Context.Entry(house).Collection(h => h.Windows).Query().Include(w => w.Kind).Load();
```

However, this will create a query that will load all `WindowKind` properties and I need only `Name`, for example. I was hoping something like this would work but it does not, `Windows` collection is empty, although the generated query looks good.

```
var house = Context.Houses.Single(h => h.ID = id);
var windows = Context.Entry(house).Collection(h => h.Windows).Query().Select(w => { new w.Color, w.Kind.Name }).Load();
```

Is it possible to have fine grained control when loading child collections?

Comment: Whats the relationship between Window and WindowKind? 1 to 1?

Comment: It's many to one, i.e. multiple windows can be of same kind.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to have fine grained control when loading navigation properties like this. You would be loading entities into the change tracker that are incomplete. You can just write a regular query that does a projection and it should be fine.

Comment: @Dismissile: I was afraid it's not possible. Could you, please, give me an example of what you meant by "writing regular query"?

Answer (score 0):

you can't load only a part of the scalar (int, string,...) properties of an entity by loading the entity.

In you case, something like the following should do:

```
from
    w in Context.Windows
where
    w.House.ID == id // here a navigation property is missing, but (imho) more clear for the sample
select new {
    windows = w,
    kName = w.Kind.Name
}
```

But in this case you will not get context attached entities.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having FK properties in dependent objects, that's why `Windows` does not have `House` or `HouseID`. I believe it could make a mess if `Window` is related to more than one class, for example `House` and `Room`.

Comment: you can avoid... i just write the sample like this

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly. In my model, you can navigate from `House` to `Window` and not in the opposite direction, `Window` does not have a reference to `House` as in the code sample you wrote.